# Custom report type not showing child objects

Tags: custom-report-type

I'm trying to create a custom report type linking two standard objects together -- Opportunity as the primary and Account as the child. I am able to create everything fine, but when I actually use the report type, no Account fields are visible.

[image]

I'm a system admin, so there shouldn't be any permission problems. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[image]

Comment: you have a custom lookup field from Account to Opportunity?  As normally, Opportunity is the child of Account

Comment: @cropredy That's probably it... I was thrown off since it let me set it up that way to begin with. Is there a way to connect two child objects to the primary? So instead of A>B>C it would basically be A>B, A>C?

Comment: Matt.  Unfortunately, no.  There’s no way for SFDC to know how to render such a schema.  The number of rows per sibling could be different.  You might consider joined reports.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta edit the report type layout to include fields from the Account. [Here's a Salesforce Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&type=5) detailing how to do so; it'll take you 15 minutes to do this if you go thru steps 1 - 9.